# Assembling Binary Tree Nodes at Runtime

Tags: c#

The getTree method must answer with a Node object that has the TAL=2 and the LEFT pointing to a Node that has its TAL=1 and the RIGHT pointing to a Node that has its TAL=3

### Anyone can help me here, ive tried many ways to make it like the description above...

```
 public class Test
{
    public Node getTree()
    {
        Node right = new Node();
        Node left = new Node();

        Node ny = new Node();
        ny.TAL = 2;

       Node ny2 = new Node();
       ny2.TAL = 1;

       Node ny3 = new Node();
       ny3.TAL = 3;

       left.LEFT = ny2;
       right.RIGHT = ny3;

    }
    public class Node
    {
        public int TAL;
        public Node LEFT;
        public Node RIGHT;

    }

}
```

Comment: You want to create three nodes, yet you create five. (Simply count how often you invoke `new Node()` in `getTree()`.) Don't you find that a bit odd?

Comment: Is this an homework assignment?

Comment: Actually it is exercises i found on the internet :)

Comment: By the way, I have edited your title. Your original title *Object and Classes* could apply to virtually all questions on SO; or it implies that you are particularly concerned about the duality of objects (instances) versus classes rather than just using some instances (your code actually just contains *one* (significant) class in all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class Test
{
    public Node getTree()
    {
        Node output = new Node();   // create tree root
        // create child nodes
        output.LEFT = new Node();
        output.RIGHT = new Node(); 
        //set TAL values
        output.TAL = 2;
        output.LEFT.TAL = 1;
        output.RIGHT.TAL = 3;
        //return tree
        return output;
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public int TAL;
        public Node LEFT;
        public Node RIGHT;

    }

}
```

You could also use constructor to set TAL property:

```
 public class Test
{
    public Node getTree()
    {
        //creates root node with TAL=2 using Node(int) constructor
        Node output = new Node(2);
        //creates left and right child nodes
        output.LEFT = new Node(1);
        output.RIGHT = new Node(3);
        return output;
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public int TAL;
        public Node LEFT;
        public Node RIGHT;

        //Node constructor that set TAL field
        public Node(int tal)    
        {
              TAL = tal;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating five Node object when you only require three.
Try this:

```
public class Test
{
    public Node getTree()
    {
        // Create the nodes
        Node parent = new Node();
        Node right = new Node();
        Node left = new Node();

        // Link them
        parent.LEFT = left;
        parent.RIGHT = right;

        // Populate their values
        parent.TAL = 2;
        right.TAL = 3;
        left.TAL = 1;

        // Return the tree
        return parent;
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public int TAL;
        public Node LEFT;
        public Node RIGHT;
    }
}
```